# awk: comment a SQL statement

Tags: regex, awk

I have a huge file with lines like

```
INSERT INTO mytable (),()...
```

I'd like to replace only those lines beginning with `INSERT INTO mytable` by

```
/* INSERT INTO mytable (),()... */
```

I know there are tons of possibilities, including good vim search replace macro, but I'd like to do it in command line.

Comment: Is using `awk` a requirement here? If yes, why? Because for example using `perl` it can be done like this: `perl -pe 's,^\s*(INSERT INTO mytable.*$),/* \1 */,g' <FILE>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the awk version:

```
 awk '{ gsub("^(INSERT.*)","/* & */"); print $0 }'
```

This is assuming that INSERT is the first character on the line. If there can be leading spaces, use this instead:

```
awk '{ gsub("^([[:space:]]*INSERT.*)","/* & */"); print $0 }'
```

This should work with non-GNU awk's as well. I tested on Linux and AIX.

Comment: I asked with awk. I dont know why they answered with sed. If I asked with awk it was to learn awk, not sed :D Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

give this sed one-liner a try:

```
sed 's#^INSERT INTO mytable.*#/* & */#' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -e "s/^INSERT INTO mytable.*/\/\* & \*\//" file.txt
```

another sed possibility